# Find word in HTML page fast algorithm

Tags: python, html, search, python-requests, cpu-word

I need to do a boolean function which returns true if a word is in the text of a HTML page and false if it's  not.

I know that it's easy to do analysing all the page tree until finding the word with the `lxml` library but I find inefficient to iterate through all the html blocks and find if the word is there.

Any suggestions for a faster algorithm (I need to do this search so many times)?

Comment: Is the word being used on many pages, or the page used for many words?

Comment: Pro-tip for future questions: Be sure to tag your question with the name of the language you're working in. I deduced that you were using Python since you mentioned the lxml library, but if you had tagged your question "python", it would have been seen by lots of master Pythonistas.

Comment: I just forgot it when I wrote the question. Sorry and thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can you preprocess the HTML pages? If you are planning on doing this search several times, it might be worth while to put the `textContent` of the HTML pages into a dedicated store, like `ElastiSearch` or 'Solr'.

Comment: I will call the function 3 or 4 times for every url, with more or less 10k different urls

Comment: Are all (or many) of those requests to the same host? If yes, you'll want to make sure to use [`requests` sessions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects), that'll speed up the networking part of your code significantly.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I'll take a look at it because all the requests go to the same host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're not worried about accidentally finding the word in an element attribute or something (and if you are worried about that, parsing the HTML with something like lxml is kind of your only option), you can just treat the entire HTML document as a big string and search for your word in it:

```
def checkForWord():
    r = requests.get("http://example.com/somepage.html")
    return "myWord" in r.text
```

Comment: It works perfect for me, thanks! I'll tag it as solution if it doesn't appear some better answer :)

Comment: Note that for Python 2.x that should be something like `u"Rodr\xedguez" in r.text` if you want to handle text containing non-ASCII characters correctly - `r.text` returns `unicode`, so the search term needs to be unicode as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get the entire page as a string:

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

And, then I'd use a method to search for the string in a string:

```
var n = markup.search("YourString");
```

You'll get a number for the index of the match or -1 if no match found.

Comment: Pretty sure he's using Python rather than JavaScript, given that [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a Python library.

Comment: You may be right, didn't mention that in the question and wasn't tagged as a python question.  Good detective work ;)

Comment: Sorry for the disambiguation, I'm using Python

Comment: No problem, my solution still holds, get the whole page as a string, search that string.  No reason to traverse the dom if you are only interested in strings

Comment: This is also @oxguy3 solution, but in Python, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, he just did a better job of actually explaining what to do instead of just providing code that does it, whoops :P